# Paypal MPL iOS Error : internal server error in iOS

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, ios8.2

I did Paypal MPL integration in my project.after I wrote the the below code in appdelegate

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
```

After I run the code I got the following error

```
checking Error********************
Posting Error: 2147483647
```

and I got the alert "Internal server error".

I wrote the above code in XCode 6.2 and running device iOS version is 8.2.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this concern?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197700/internal-server-error-with-paypal-mpl     This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error with "Posting Error: -1" with alert "internal server error".

Just add Bundle display name in your info.plist of your project as an empty.

Here's the screenshot.

[image]