# Internal Server Error with PayPal MPL

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to use PayPalMPL 2.1.7 for iOS to accept third party payments in my app. When I use this code to initialize the environment:

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
```

I get this error in the log:
Checking Error********************
Posting Error: -1

and this error as an alert in the app:
Error
internal server error

I would love to upgrade to the new PayPal iOS SDK, but it doesn't offer third party payments yet.
Any idea what will fix these errors?
Thanks!

Comment: Please put the your comment - "Fixed this by adding Bundle Display Name in info.plist" as answer and accept it so that people looking for answer will find it easily.

Comment: Just posted the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

However the question has an answer, I would like to add my two cents for future beginners like me who may found the same error.

Just add `Bundle display name` in your info.plist of your project as an empty.

Here's the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding Bundle Display Name in info.plist